# Use of uninitialized value in foreach loop

Tags: perl, foreach

Piece of my code:

```
my $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new;
Proc::Daemon::Init(
    {   work_dir     => '/home/olex/develop',
        child_STDOUT => '/home/olex/develop/output.file',
        child_STDERR => '+>>debug.txt'
    }
);
if ( Proc::PID::File->running() ) {
    print "Already running\n";
    exit 0;
}
my @kids = ( 1 .. 4 );
my @childs;
my $kid_pid;
foreach $kid_pid (@kids) {
    $kid_pid = $daemon->Init(
        {   work_dir     => '/home/olex/develop',
            pid_file     => "kid_pid.pid",
            exec_command => 'perl /home/olex/develop/remote_imapd.pl',
        }
    );
    $childs[$kid_pid] = $daemon->Status($kid_pid);
}
print @childs, "\n";
my $string = join( ',', @childs );
print $string;
```

One element of array `@childs` is uninitialized in STDERR, but result of print is ok! After `join` results in about a `,,.....,,2450,,2452,,2454,,2456`. Why so? I understand that the problem in the loop, but i seem to be doing everything correctly. I need string like `2450,2452,2454,2456`.

Comment: result is similar if i use `$childs[$kid_pid] = $kid_pid;`

Comment: You seem to be saying that your error was that the entire array was uninitialized, whereas it looks like only one element (the first) was, and your error was really `Use of uninitialized value within @childs in join or string`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edited.

Comment: You cannot get `,,.....,,2450,,2452,,2454,,2456` in output from the above code. You should copy/paste the real output you get.

Comment: `.....` it's a lot `,,,` :)

Comment: Yes, but there cannot be "a lot", since you only have indexes `1 .. 4`. So your output should be `,2450,2452,2454,2456`, and no double commas `,,`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As near as I can tell from your code and the vague description of your error, your problem is an uninitialized element in your array. This would mean that your error was:

```
Use of uninitialized value within @childs in join or string
```

You should always copy/paste the error exactly as it appears. Never do anything else, because it is a waste of time.

If you print your array with the core module `Data::Dumper`, e.g. :

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
print Dumper \@childs;
```

I suspect you will get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          2050,
          2051,
          2052,
          2053
        ];
```

Where you can clearly see that element `0` is undef. This comes from using

```
my @kids = (1..4);
...
foreach $kid_pid (@kids) {
   ...
   $childs[$kid_pid] = $daemon->Status($kid_pid);
}
```

Where the array gets the indexes 1 through 4 initialized, but not the first element number zero `0`. In Perl, array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

To avoid problems like this, do not assign directly to the array index, but instead use `push`:

```
push @childs, $daemon->Status($kid_pid);
```

Unless, of course, you need the index for something.

Comment: Yes, it's my carelessness. Thank you.